# How to change font size of the input in airDatepicker from shinywidgets package?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinywidgets

I'm using `airDatepicker` from the `shinyWidgets` package. Here's my code:

```
airDatepickerInput(inputId = "choosedate", label = "month range", range = TRUE, placeholder = "choose month range", dateFormat = "M yy", view = "months", minView = "months", clearButton = TRUE,
autoClose = TRUE, update_on = "close", inline = FALSE, monthsField = "monthsShort", separator = " - ",
width = "161px", value = c("2010-01-01", "2019-12-31"), addon = "right")
```

I also use `tags$style` to put all of my CSS code. Currently the font of `airDatepicker` (the input, not the label) is way too large for the rest of my dashboard. Here's the parts which fonts I want to make smaller :

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxBDB.png)

How do I do it? Thank you.

Comment: The font size of the label?

Comment: no, the content of the input. I will edit my question

Comment: Okay, please check my edit.

Comment: Thank you very much, @ismirsehregal! It works very well.

Comment: If you don't mind, would you please check my other question related to airDatepicker? Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59187457/how-do-i-change-the-size-of-calendar-icon-in-airdatepicker-from-shinywidget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to find the correct selectors (e.g. with your browser):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
                            #choosedate {font-size: 75%}
                            #datepickers-container > div > nav {font-size: 75%;}
                            #datepickers-container > div > div.datepicker--content {font-size: 75%;}
                            #datepickers-container > div > div.datepicker--buttons > span {font-size: 75%;}
                            '))),
  airDatepickerInput(inputId = "choosedate", label = "month range", range = TRUE, placeholder = "choose month range", dateFormat = "M yy", view = "months", minView = "months", clearButton = TRUE,
                     autoClose = TRUE, update_on = "close", inline = FALSE, monthsField = "monthsShort", separator = " - ",
                     width = "161px", value = c("2010-01-01", "2019-12-31"), addon = "right")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Before][image: After]